# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime with the format of "MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss tt"

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string into a DateTime in C#, but I'm getting this error:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

The error is in the next line:

```
DateTime endTime = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

My `endDate` variable has the following info: "10/03/2017 06:52:48 AM"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This does not give me any errors: `DateTime.ParseExact("10/03/2017 06:52:48 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);` are you sure the input string is exactly what you say it is?

Comment: Hi @RufusL, thanks for trying it, yes I am sure, I copied the string with a breakpoint.

Comment: Sorry @Servy.  I'll stop editing and let you fix it. :)

Comment: @BJMyers No worries, should be all taken care of now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `null` as an `IFormatProvider`, all `DateTime` parsing methods use [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) settings of your computer.

There are a few possibilities that you get exception. For example, your `CurrentCulture` might *not* have `AM` as it's [`AMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator) property.

Instead of that, use a *proper* culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

```
DateTime endTime = DateTime.ParseExact("10/03/2017 06:52:48 AM", 
                                       "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: or put the local equivalent of AM / PM in the date string to be converted

Comment: which you can find here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: Thank you so much @Soner Gönül !! this solved myproblem